# Spacetime symmetries

Tags: gr.group-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity, isometries

We know some nice space-time have a lot of symmetries. It is said that

- Minkowski spacetime has
  $$ISO(d-1,1)/SO(d-1,1),$$
- de Sitter spacetime has 
  $$SO(d,1)/SO(d-1,1)$$ and
- anti-de Sitter  spacetime has
  $$SO(d-1,2)/SO(d-1,1).$$

e.g. see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75604/42982

One then is interested in unitary irreducible representations of the space-time symmetry group.

> Question: Is this correct that the above is the symmetry of Minkowski, de Sitter spacetime, and anti-de Sitter  spacetime? It this the same as the isometry of these spacetimes? How to show this is the complete symmetry?